# Android Studio Firebase returning null on getkey and getvalue

Tags: java, android, firebase

I gave up debugging this problem
I already check many posts and my code is similar to them
I think my code is right but it always keep returning null

```
package com.example.dejabrew;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CartList extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewInterface {

    TextView finalprice;
    Integer getprice;
    Integer Finalprice = 0;
    ImageView home, favourite;
    RecyclerView cartrecyclerview;
    RecyclerViewAdapter2 recyclerViewAdapter2;
    ArrayList<Cartmodel> list;
    ArrayList<Integer> pricelist = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://dejabrew-2bcc8-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cartlist);

        finalprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalprice);
        cartrecyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.cartrecyclerview);
        cartrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home2);
        favourite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.heart2);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = (new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        cartrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerViewAdapter2 = new RecyclerViewAdapter2(this, this, list);
        cartrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter2);

        databaseReference.child("AddtoCart").child("Orders").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Cartmodel cartmodel = dataSnapshot.getValue(Cartmodel.class);
                    list.add(cartmodel);
                }
                recyclerViewAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        databaseReference.child("AddtoCart").child("Orders").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {;
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: snapshot1.getChildren()){
                    String getkey = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                    getprice = snapshot1.child(getkey).child("price").getValue(Integer.class);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CartList.this, HomePage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onitemclick(int position) {
        Cartmodel cartmodel = list.get(position);
        String id = cartmodel.getItemid();
        databaseReference.child("AddtoCart").child("Orders").child(id).removeValue();
        recyclerViewAdapter2.notifyItemRemoved(position);

    }
}
```

[[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5reCs.png)][Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPu1j.png)

I need to get all the price value of items in cart to get the total price
Here is the image of my firebase realtime database and the picture of the debugger

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

I needed to place my code inside the event listener because of Firebase being asynchronous.